# How to resample the data by month and plot monthly percentages?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe in which matches played by a team in a year is given. `Match Date` is a column.

```
        Team 1     Team 2       Winner Match Date
5      Australia    England      England 2018-01-14
12     Australia    England      England 2018-01-19
14     Australia    England      England 2018-01-21
20     Australia    England    Australia 2018-01-26
22     Australia    England      England 2018-01-28
34   New Zealand    England  New Zealand 2018-02-25
35   New Zealand    England      England 2018-02-28
36   New Zealand    England      England 2018-03-03
43   New Zealand    England  New Zealand 2018-03-07
46   New Zealand    England      England 2018-03-10
62      Scotland    England     Scotland 2018-06-10
63       England  Australia      England 2018-06-13
64       England  Australia      England 2018-06-16
65       England  Australia      England 2018-06-19
66       England  Australia      England 2018-06-21
67       England  Australia      England 2018-06-24
68       England      India        India 2018-07-12
70       England      India      England 2018-07-14
72       England      India      England 2018-07-17
106    Sri Lanka    England    no result 2018-10-10
107    Sri Lanka    England      England 2018-10-13
108    Sri Lanka    England      England 2018-10-17
109    Sri Lanka    England      England 2018-10-20
112    Sri Lanka    England    Sri Lanka 2018-10-23
```

`Match Date` is in datetime. I could plot the number of matches played versus winning matches. This is the code I used.

```
England.set_index('Match Date', inplace = True)
England.resample('1M').count()['Winner'].plot()
England_win.resample('1M').count()['Winner'].plot()
```

But I would like to plot the winning percentage by month. Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Could you post at least a sample of your dataframe to reproduce the issue, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are more efficient ways to do this, but one way to plot this using an approach similar to yours:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#reading your sample data
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\s{2,}", parse_dates=["Match Date"], index_col="ID", engine="python")
df.set_index('Match Date', inplace = True)

#creating df that count the wins
df1 = df[df["Winner"]=="England"].resample("1M").count()
#calculate and plot the percentage - if no game, NaN values are substituted with zero
df1.Winner.div(df.resample('1M').count()['Winner']).mul(100).fillna(0).plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]